# DIY: how to make double-layer install DVD?

Tags: opensuse

Facts:

- online repo (official) is more than 20GB -- I have access to it
- downloadable DVD is for single layer disks  -- I have access to it
- boxed openSUSE DVD is double layer -- I do **NOT** have access to it

Is it possible and if yes -- how -- to make this double-layer DVD on your own? Legally of course.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, legally.

The [OpenSuSE Build Factory](https://build.opensuse.org/project/show%3Fproject%3DopenSUSE%3AFactory) lists all the packages available from OpenSUSE.  All packages are Open Source and free to download, so you may assemble enough content to fill a bootable double-layer DVD.

The [openSUSE KIWI Image Wiki](http://en.opensuse.org/openSUSE%3aBuild_Service_KIWI) has tutorials on how to do that, and the manual is on line at [Open Build Service Reference Guide](http://openbuildservice.org/help/manuals/obs-reference-guide/).

As to obtaining the boxed set, well, the only boxed set I saw http://en.opensuse.org/Buy_openSUSE was in German as confirmed at http://opensuse-guide.org/acquisition.php . One disc is a LiveDVD and the other the 'biarch' DVD. You can download both from http://mirror.anl.gov/pub/opensuse/opensuse/distribution/13.1/iso/ and then combine the two into an ISO large enough to fill a dual-layer DVD, but do you need biarch files?

Comment: Thank you, but I don't need any double-layer DVD, I need the one it is distributed as boxed one. And repo is more than double layer DVD so selecting the right packages is crucial.